# How to insert special characters into mysql database using pymysql

Tags: mysql, pymysql

I am trying to insert special characters into mysql database using pymysql. My database character set is utf4mb4 and collation is utf8mb4_bin. I can run this query directly from my mysql interface. But whenever I try to do it with pymysql I get error. Below is the sql statement.

```
insert into users(name, location) values('ABCDEFGH ⚜️⚔️', 'City Name, Country')
```

Comment: What's your pymysql version? Few of the encoding issues are fixed in the latest versions.

Comment: how do you find it?

Comment: pip show pymysql

Comment: Name: PyMySQL
Version: 0.9.2
Summary: Pure Python MySQL Driver
Home-page: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/
Author: yutaka.matsubara
Author-email: yutaka.matsubara@gmail.com
License: "MIT"
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: cryptography

Comment: Hope this helps